# Does elasticsearch supports this kind of query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a query with following term.
It checks if a date is between a range

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "range": {
          "start_date": {
            "lt": "2017-09-13"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "end_date": {
            "gt": "2017-09-13"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in one `range` instead of using two different `range` terms and `must`.
e.g. something like this

```
{
  "range": {
    "2017-09-13": {
      "gt": "start_date",
      "lt": "end_date"
    }
  }
}
```

Or is there any other way of doing this

Comment: no, you need one range per field... or do equivalent query in a single `query_string` query

Comment: @Val how can be `query_string` formed for this case? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to add constraints on two different fields, you need two `range` queries.

If you really want a single query without `bool/must`, you could eventually use a `query_string` query with a condition like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "start_date:<2017-09-13 AND end_date:>2017-09-13"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. I am ok with what am doing before :). I have an other question, will be grateful if you can help.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/45943497/6143836